# laravel 4 local developing but I want to use a remote database

Tags: database, laravel-4

I have set up xampp server where I am developing a laravel app:
Every day (when I make an update to my app) I have to export and import the SQL from the database. That takes a lot of time if I have worked on 10 apps that day :(
Is there a way I can use the online database with a local test version of laravel?

I am using shared hosting and not migrations. I insert tables myself. 
Online I see a tab:

```
access hosts: 'localhost'
```

I can add a host, but what name should I add and how can I get laravel to access this host?
Could it be 'subdomain.mywebsitename.nl/hostname'?
I'm too scared my app will crash if I change it :s

---

This i tried this after the solution i got:

I filled in a host. This is the same url i fill in my adress bar.

```
 'host'      => 'http://safetyanalyse.nl:2222/',

  'host'      => 'http://safetyanalyse.nl',
```

Both options do not work :(  Do i have to put the port number somewhere else?

I also have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'D97A1650.cm-3-3a.dynamic.ziggo.nl' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

---

Step 2 (next i tried this).

In the error it says something about the host, i tried filling in this host.

```
  'host'      => 'D97A1650.cm-3-3a.dynamic.ziggo.nl',
```

Now i get the error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'safety_cert-user'@'d97a1650.cm-3-3a.dynamic.ziggo.nl' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use domain name as host, that should work.
Also, look for port, if specified.

All this information should be provided to you is hosting control panel. If not, I would change hosting provider.

**Edit**
Define your host without protocol.
In your `app/config/database.php`set

```
'host' => 'safetyanalyse.nl',
```

Comment: i have added a little bit.